# Print text to shell without advancing buffer

Tags: c, shell, terminal, console

I would like to know if there is a way to print text into shell's current buffer/cursor so it can be edited. I am building a program that will store some text values in memory and need a simple way to edit them in the shell without rewriting the whole value. So somehow referencing the current edit buffer in shell and printing to it would be quite nice.

However, I am only using common sense here. Maybe it is more complicated. Looking forward to possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Every shell handles user input differently. If there is an "edit buffer", it is most likely to be implemented in the shell itself. (Linux terminals do have a primitive line-editing function but as far as I know, there's no way to inject data into the line. However, only very primitive shells rely on native line-editing.)

So the question must be asked with respect to some specific shell.

Just in case, here's the answer for bash.

Bash relies on the `readline` library to perform command input from a terminal(-like) standard input. (Command-line history is provided using a related `history` library.) These libraries have a lot of features and bash does not provide access to all of them; if necessary, you could write a program in C or some scripting language with a readline binding.

But bash does give you the tools necessary to preload input with a line of text. The standard way of collecting input from a shell script is through the `read` command, which is (almost) always a shell "built-in". Basic ooeration of `read` is defined by the Posix standard, but the bash version provides a lot of useful extension options, including:

- `-e`: use the `readline` library (with tab-completion, history and line editing enabked).
- `-i text`: if `readline` is being used, preload readline's edit buffer with the specified text.

The
[bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) has lots more information about the `read` command's options.